# can I combine 2 raster with wavelet transform in R?

Tags: image-processing, wavelet, dwt

I Have same problem, i will combine 2 raster data with wavelet fusion

```
r1<-brick("mask data/r1_mask_black.tif")
r2<-brick("mask data/r2_mask_black.tif")
```